# 5.5. month old not eating as well anymore

Tags: infant, feeding

I have triplets and my bigger one has slowly been taking less and less and now the other two have surpassed him. His weight curve has also slowed down but nothing to be concerned about according to our pediatrician. I am bottle feeding. To put it in perspective - my other two have been eating on average 1100ml/day and this one is eating 980ml/day. This may seem like a lot but over time this is a considerably lower amount of calories.

I am just wondering if anyone else had a superstar eater turn into a ho-hum eater? Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I haven't had this particular situation, but I do think it's important to remember that kids go through cycles in their eating habits.  Is he LOSING weight or failing to GAIN weight?  Does he have any other signs or symptoms to make you think he's sick or not feeling well?  If not, then he's probably ok.  Keep on eye on him, monitor his eating, make sure he's not exhibiting other signs of illness, but if he's happy and healthy otherwise then at his next growth spurt it will probably pick back up again.

Comment: Maybe he's just done spurting for right now and the others are playing catch-up?

Answer (score 2):

Here's some helpful information from the [Livestrong Foundation](http://www.livestrong.com/article/531135-why-is-my-baby-not-eating-as-much-as-normal/#ixzz2RWaRLkVm):

> **Causes of Slowed Appetite**
>
> If your baby's suddenly eating less but seems to still be healthy and
> interested in eating, he’s likely just going through a healthy slow
> phase. In a baby 4 to 7 months old, eating less can also indicate he’s
> beginning teething. If you think his teeth are coming in, give him a
> cold washcloth to chew on and ask his doctor if you can give him a
> pain reliever. In some cases, his eating less could indicate a larger
> medical problem. Consult a pediatrician if you suspect something's
> wrong.
>
> **Signs Your Baby is Healthy**
>
> Your baby's change in hunger could be a normal and healthy thing. Pay
> attention to how many diapers you’re changing. A baby who’s getting
> enough nourishment should wet five to six diapers and have at least
> one bowel movement a day. She should seem relaxed and content after
> each feeding. Your baby's skin should be smooth and unwrinkled and her
> face should be rounded by her third week of life. If you’re
> breastfeeding, your breasts should feel softer after a feeding.
>
> **Signs
> of a Problem**
>
> A baby who is not getting enough daily nourishment will not urinate as
> frequently, and his urine may be dark yellow or orange. He may only
> pass bowel movements once every few days and they may be hard and dry.
> If he seems fussy after eating or expresses no interest in eating,
> this may also indicate a problem. Your baby’s weight is one of the
> surest ways to track whether he’s eating enough. A healthy baby should
> steadily gain weight after his first day of life. If he’s not gaining
> -- or is losing -- weight, visit his pediatrician immediately.